# Params inside of Warden's strategy is empty when I try to authenticate through ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, warden, query-string

I'm trying to use Warden for authentication in my rails app. And it works fine if I use it with regular form via POST request. But when I moved it to Backbone.js I found that authenticate! method always calls my failure app.

I put some logging inside of authenticate! method and found that params hash is empty. Like that:

```
def authenticate!
    Rails.logger.debug "Parameters inside of Warden: #{params}"
    user = User.find_by_email(params['email'])
    if user && user.authenticate(params['password'])
      success! user
    else
      fail "Invalid email #{request.params['email']} or password #{request.params['password']}!"
    end
end
```

It generates an empty output:
    Parameters inside of Warden: {}

At the same time I can see params in controller before env['warden'].authenticate! is called.
I can only guess where my parameters gone. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm kind a new to Rails so my solution could be trivial. But as I didn't find anything related to it, It may be useful for somebody.

The point is that Warden instantiate Rack::Request to get an access to params hash. And it only supports 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and 'multipart/form-data'. 
http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html#M000275

Probably there is a different parser used in controller that's why I was confused. Finally I fixed it with external Rack-based Parser:
https://github.com/achiu/rack-parser

Comment: It seams that warden clears out the params hash for whatever security reason, if authentication fails.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm quite late to meet the same issue, but still want to provide some help.

Like Ivan said, the request in Rails controller and in strategy are different things. It's an instance of Rack::Request in strategy but ActionDispatch::Request in Rails controller.
My approach is to do what devise do, which is to patch this behavior:

```
# config/initializers/warden.rb
module Warden
  module Mixins
    module Common
      def request
        @request ||= ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

you can also check what devise do [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb)